# Where are application settings saved?

Tags: vb.net, settings

I am trying to store some persistent application data so I've added a setting to the project by R-Clicking on it, selecting properties, then Settings tab and manually entering settings name, Type, Scope and Value

When I run the code, I read settings like this:

`lastRunTime = My.Settings.LastRunTime`

and set it like this:

`My.Settings.LastRunTime = lastRunTime`

Where can I actually see the new setting? Because for the love of God, I cannot see where it is updating the setting. app.config has the original setting value when I created that setting. So where can I see it?

When I run the code, I see it updates it and the next time I run the app the new value persists, so I know it stores it somewhere. But where?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

.NET has to do something special, it has to give you a guarantee that *another* program that also happens to have a "LastRuntime" setting *doesn't* overwrite the value that's stored for your program.  To do that, it stores a user.config file in a directory that's hard to find back.  It has a weirdo name, like

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1._Url_twchbbo4atpsvjpauzkgkvesu5bh2aul\1.0.0.0\user.config

Note how the project name is part of the path, that's one way to find it back.  The unspeakable part of the name is a *hash*, created from various properties of your project that make your app unique enough to not collide with another .NET program, even if the name matches.  Like your product name, company name, exe name, etcetera.

Note how the converse is true as well, changing such a property makes you lose your user.config file.  So if "LastRuntime" is some kind of license metering value then using a setting isn't the best idea.

Comment: Yes, that's the one! found the file with the up-to-date LastRunDate. That explains where it is stored. Would you be able to point out why its doing it though? I want it to work with a local version of the config file, the one located in the same folder as the executable and not located in a user folder.

Comment: You get the "local version" by changing the scope of the setting from "User" to "Application".  But that doesn't work for your kind of setting because that doesn't allow you to save the value back.  The app.exe.config is stored in a directory that you cannot write to without UAC elevation.  If you don't like the way settings work then just cook your own, just a file saved to an AppData folder.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to keep everything in a single file. I guess I will have to create a local INI file to store the variable and to keep the file in the same folder.

Comment: ... or actually I can use AppSettings to store that variable. The reason I was trying Settings is I have a bunch of comments explaining each variable in AppSettings, but when I save the variable, all comments are automatically removed from AppSettings (all of them, not just for the variable)

Answer (score 1):

That value is stored in the APPDATA folder under your user profile. For Windows 7 look in C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\

There will be a folder named based on how you configured Visual Studio. Since my copy at work is registered to the company, the default value is my company name. Since my copy of Visual Studio at home is registered to myself, the default value is my name.

AppData is a hidden folder, that won't show up if you navigate via Windows Explorer. But if you type it into the run command it will open with no problems.

Comment: I can find no file. There is a folder with the company name and some folders for other projects I've been working, but not the current project that I am having problems with. I did a search on C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\ searching for all subfolders for *.config and haven't found my project's config file

Comment: Then look in the "<User>\AppData\Local\" folder.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if this is a machine-level setting or a user level setting.

For machine-level settings, the app.config file in your project only stores the original setting used for development, so that when you finish building the app and deploy it to production or deliver to your customer, that default value will be there on first install.

When you change the value during debugging, your program is (by default) in a `/bin/Debug/` folder off the root of the project. There will be another an app.config file there that includes the project as part of the file name: `project.app.config`. This is where your saved settings go.

An important thing to remember here is that, by default, your app is deployed to a folder in the Program Files directory, and also that standard users, by default, don't have write access to this location. This means that application level settings can't be changed by standard users.

For user-level settings, a similar process happens. However, there is one important difference. Instead of living in the same folder as your app, it uses your user's AppData folder instead. This means that standard users do have write access, and the ability to change the setting. However, it means finding your config file is a bit tricky, because you have to protect against two applications with the same name trying to store the config file in the same folder.

Comment: None of the `.config` files have the data i am saving. When I run the program, I read the LastRunTime variable, log it, assign `Now` to it and save it. Next time I run the app, new value is logged so it seems to be saving the value, but where?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did

```
My.Settings.LastRunTime = lastRunTime
My.Settings.Save() '-----------------> maybe you forgot this
```

I'm sure you can read the setting with ..

```
lastRunTime = My.Settings.LastRunTime
```

Comment: I did not forget to save. It saves and it reads the value just fine. I didn't know where it was saving it to though