# .NET Winform Settings file location

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When you create suppose C# Winform application and go to project properties there is this tab called settings which allows you to store some variables. so when user closes application and runs it again those values would not be lost. So as I guess somewhere some file is created to store the values declared in settings tab. Does anybody know where this file is located at?

Comment: have you tried google ? or tried to enter some settings and then to look for a file or the .csproj main file ?

Comment: It depends on how you build your application, but these are sent to the /bin/debug or /bin/release folder by default when you build a winforms application.  Tons and tons of information on MSDN you can find by typing your *exact title* in google.  Which should have been your first stop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are the Properties.Default.Settings stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982354/where-are-the-properties-default-settings-stored)

Comment: I tried. I could not find it. that's why I asked. thank anyways

Comment: possible duplicate of [Settings in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244665/settings-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 6):

If you tried to add settings you wanted to persist, you would have been able to see them in
`YourApp.exe.config` file which is in the same directory where is build output binary.

For settings like this:

[image]

...`WindowsFormsApplication1.exe.config` file (generated by the Visual Studio and placed in the same directory where it output `WindowsFormsApplication1.exe`) contains settings you added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <userSettings>
        <WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="UserSetting" serializeAs="String">
                <value>UserValue</value>
            </setting>
        </WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
    <applicationSettings>
        <WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="AppSetting" serializeAs="String">
                <value>AppValue</value>
            </setting>
        </WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

From MSDN's [Application Settings Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx):

> - Application-scoped settings can be stored in either the machine.config
>     or app.exe.config files. Machine.config is always read-only, while
>     app.exe.config is restricted by security considerations to read-only
>     for most applications.
> - User-scoped settings can be stored in app.exe.config files, in which case they are treated as static
>     defaults.
> - Non-default user-scoped settings are stored in a new file,
>     user.config

Further down you can see file locations:

> The location of the app.exe.config and user.config files will differ
>   based on how the application is installed. For a Windows Forms-based
>   application copied onto the local computer, app.exe.config will reside
>   in the same directory as the base directory of the application's main
>   executable file, and user.config will reside in the location specified
>   by the Application.LocalUserAppDataPath property.