# can not find the user level setting saved by Visual studio 2012 in my C# form application

Tags: c#, settings

I have made a small simple c# form application in which I have added a user level setting of colour type(with default value red) and added a button on form. When I click on the button the back ground colour of form will changes to red and if a press the button again its colour changes to blue.When I close the window form background colour will saved and next time saved colour is loaded.
I use the following line to save the colour can any one tell me the file in which Visual Studio save this colour. ?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.BackColor == Color.Blue)
            {
                this.BackColor = Color.Red;
                Properties.Settings.Default.backcolor = Color.Red;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                Properties.Settings.Default.backcolor = Color.Blue;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Here is a post that shows teh path http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f3e1f68-d19c-4a43-a650-bd4afa9c4593/c-application-settings-where-are-they-stored

Comment: I think the file is under `Properties` folder, it it there?

Comment: It is somewhere under the AppData folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are application settings saved?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244665/where-are-application-settings-saved)

Comment: thanks all i have find my user_config file :)