# vb.net, my.settings and stand alone exe

Tags: vb.net, deployment, clickonce, application-settings

I've made an application in Visual Basic Express which utilizes the My.Settings features. I'm looking to compile the code into a single .exe, with the my.settings in the .exe folder. Also, the code uses an "Assets" folder in the exe root folder at various places via relative path names.

Thus, what I'm looking for is a way to have a single folder with the exe in the root of this; settings saved also within the folder and and Assets folder in it also. I'd like the user to be able to place the folder wherever they want.

Looking into Click-once, it's looking like the application gets installed in some kind of Roaming/app data folder and that this isn't choose-able. Thus, this isn't suitable

With other applications I've designed, I just lifted the exe from the debug/release folder, but these were where accessing settings was coded via direct accessing files rather than via the My.Settings system. In some ways, I really do wish I hadn't used my.settings now!

What's the best way to achieve the above? Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Where are app settings saved? Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244665/where-are-application-settings-saved), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691858/where-are-my-settings-saved-in-vb-2010-net).

Comment: My.Settings are written to `Users...`.  You ought not care since VB gets and saves them for you.  Depending on these "assets", you should follow suit since your app may not have permission to write to the EXE folder when installed to `Program Files...`