# Where does a console application REALLY store its settings

Tags: vb.net

I've created a console app (VS2015, target framework 4.5.2) and I have used `My Project/Settings` to create application level settings. All the documentation and answers here on stackoverflow.com tell me (and this is the way I've always understood it to work) that the `app.config` file are where these things are stored and I can indeed see these settings in app.config and I can open `settings.vb` to look at the properties and their default values.

So far so good, when I compiled this and chucked ONLY the executable on a different machine, as expected it worked. I am assuming this is because `settings.vb` is compiled into the app.

But I am left with an application for which I can't change the settings. Where do I now put the `app.config` so that I can indeed change the settings in the XML and have my application use those settings instead of the default ones next time? I hope I don't have to build an installer or do a publish because to me that completely defeats the purpose of console applications.

Comment: I don't know what you can do with the `app.config`, I think you can ship it with your application, but the first time you start an application on a computer a settings file will be generated in a location looking something like this: `%LocalAppData%\[Your Company Name]\[Your App Name And Version with other random letters]`.

Comment: I am not seeing that location...

Comment: Closest I get is: `C:\Users\myusernamehere\AppData\Local`

Comment: And you see no folder containing your app's file name/company name?

Comment: No I sure don't :-(

Comment: Hmm, that's strange... I'll see if I can dig something up tomorrow. In the meantime [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17245548/3740093) explains what I am talking about.

Comment: It is indeed a bit strange I read that one too... Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the settings in `app.config` are also embedded into your code (just for those situations like what you describe... where you just have the EXE without any `*.config` file).  You can change this behavior by changing the `GenerateDefaultValueInCode` for each setting.

There are two sections to the file... the application section has the read-only setting for the entire app.  The user section has the starting default values of the settings that the user can change.

So, just to review:

- `app.config` = the design-time version of all the settings (it gets
  renamed and copied to `bin`)
- `YourApplication.exe.config` = the run-time
  version of the all of the settings
- `%LOCALAPPDATA%\App\Version\user.config` = just the user portion of the
  settings after they've made changes

Comment: One thing to note... The application targets framework 4.5.2. On the destination machine this version is NOT available. When I copy JUST the executable, it gracefully dumbs down to a lower version. When I add the `myapplication.exe.config` it stops functioning and asks me to install version 4.5.2. When you edit the `config` file all is well again. Just something to look out for.